# materiul-ui buttons override modal window react

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How to disable overlay for materiul-ui buttons `RaisedButton`.

I have a modal window and when I open it - buttons are still shown.

What property should I add to my buttons to disable overlay?

Please who works with material-ui, help.

Screen is bellow [image]

I tried to use z-index for button's container but did not help

Comment: please add some relevant code

Answer (score 1):

I added `z-index` and `position` to button, now it is ok.

```js
 <div className={styles.watch__button}>
          <RaisedButton
            onClick={buttonRole}
            backgroundColor={timerButtonColor}
            style={{zIndex: 0, position: 'relative'}}>
            <div className={styles.watch__button__text}>{buttonName}</div>
          </RaisedButton>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.watch__button}>
          <RaisedButton
            onClick={this.handleShowCalendar}
            backgroundColor={genButtonColor}
            style={{zIndex: 0, position: 'relative'}}>
            <div className={styles.watch__button__text}>Generate</div>
          </RaisedButton>
        </div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={showCalendar} >
          <button onClick={this.handleShowCalendar}>close</button>
          <h1>Modal Content</h1>
        </Modal >
```

Maybe somebody know how to make it with class, because it works only with style